# Resource file not found after war file deployed upon wildfly8

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, jboss, wildfly

I've created dynamic web project in Eclipse and added it to ear project.

Image resources are placed at src\resources\

Code use resources:

```
@GET
@Path("bank")
@Produces("application/json")
public String getBank(@Context HttpHeaders headers) {
  ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
  File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("/resources/alfa.png").getFile());
  String base64 = Utility.getBase64(file);
  return "{\"icon\":\"" + base64 + "\"}";
}
```

While debugging it's OK.

When ear deployed code throws exception:
     java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\apps\wildfly-8.2.0.Final\bin\content\TimerService.ear\timer.war\WEB-INF\classes\resources\alfa.png

All resources are present in war-file contained in ear-file.

What is wrong?

Comment: You can't reference class path resources as java.o.File objects because they will often not exist file system as distinct file system objects.  Modify Utility.getBase64 to take a java.io.InputStream instead.

Comment: Check out all the answers at [getResourceAsStream() vs FileInputStream](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308188/getresourceasstream-vs-fileinputstream) for more information. I'm sure your question is a dupe but I can't find a good match

Comment: Thanks Steve.  getResourceAsStream() is solution.

Answer (score 0):

this way it should work

```
@GET
@Path("bank")
@Produces("application/json")
public String getBank(@Context final HttpServletRequest request) {
  ClassLoader classLoader = request.getServletContext().getClassLoader();
  File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("/resources/alfa.png").getFile());
  String base64 = Utility.getBase64(file);
  return "{\"icon\":\"" + base64 + "\"}";
}
```